SpringBoot security standard MFA sample does not work the way it should
I am new to spring boot security and trying to get this standard sample to work: servlet/spring-boot/java/authentication/username-password/mfa but both MfaApplicationTests as the MfaApplication don´t work for me.
Perhaps my first remark should be that I had to adjust the build.gradle file to make it compile. The 2 plugin lines with alias are not accepted.
alias(libs.plugins.org.springframework.boot)
alias(libs.plugins.io.spring.dependency.management)

I replaced them with:
id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.4.0"

That solved the compile problem.
But running the samples still gives me an error which I can't figure out.
MfaApplicationTests Test, first part (but all 5 fail with the same problem).
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "example.MfaAuthentication.getPrincipal()" because "authentication" is null (see attachments) 

MfaApplication
Here I can log in as user@example.com but after I enter the MFA code this happens:
2024-12-10T13:01:54.810+01:00 ERROR 18097 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "example.MfaAuthentication.getPrincipal()" because "authentication" is null] with root cause

I am running JDK 19, Netbeans 19, Gradle 8.11.1, Spring Boot 3.4.0
Even to me it is clear that authentication is null, but I can't figure out why. Does anyone has a clue, I already wasted lots of hours but couldn't get any further. Thanks for helping.
I scanned the sources but can't see where authentication should be initialised. I put in a couple of my own System.out.println to see what exactly happens ,but this did not really help.
The below method processSecondFactor() should already have the initialised authentication but it does not. But this method is called from /second-factor.
@PostMapping("/second-factor")
public void processSecondFactor(
        @RequestParam("code") String code,
        MfaAuthentication authentication,
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        
    MfaAuthenticationHandler handler = new MfaAuthenticationHandler("/third-factor");

    if (authentication == null) System.out.println(" MFA Controller >>>> authentication == null ");
                
    String secret = getSecret(authentication);
    if (this.mfaService.check(secret, code)) {
        handler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication.getFirst());
    } else {
        handler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, new BadCredentialsException("bad credentials"));
    }
}


Please take care of properly formatting your question. Currently it is impossible to determine what is text and what is code. You are following some sort of tutorial please link to that tutorial (feels like you are following an old one).

Sorry for that, I see now that this could be done better. The source code is copied from github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/authentication/username-password/mfa. I'll pass some source code examples as soon as I find out how to do that properly.
